# Тире/двоеточие всё-таки?

Tags: пунктуация

Оба варианта правильны? Я знаю, что 1-й по-любому правильный.

> Есть ещё один способ справиться со своими проблемами — найти любовь.

> Есть ещё один способ справиться со своими проблемами: найти любовь.

Comment: Ссылка исправлена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[10-й пункт «Розенталя»](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111). Здесь приложение или пояснение, но ни в коем случае не конструкция с обобщающим словом, — некорректно так распологать двоеточие, да и кроме тире вообще неуместен другой знак:

*Есть ещё один способ справиться со своими проблемами — найти любовь*.

Только тире — больше ничего.

Answer (score 2):

(1) *Есть ещё один способ / справиться со своими проблЕмами (какой именно?): **найти любОвь***.

Интонационное предупреждение, понижение тона, предупредительная пауза, вторая часть более **значима**.

Присоединительное тире (понижение голоса, меньшая пауза) не подходит по смыслу.

Сравнить:

(2) *Ещё один способ решить проблему — (это) **найти любовь.***

Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, повышение тона перед паузой. Нераспространенное предложение.